# Tumblr: Changing Post attributes based on tag?

Tags: css, themes, tumblr, meta

I'm looking to make a basic tumblr profile using the 101 theme (https://www.tumblr.com/theme/483) which is white and every entry has a different color depending on what type of post it is, so for example, a regular entry could be blue and a video entry could be green.

I know this is defined using the `metaname` option; `<meta name="color:Regular Entry" content="#000000"/>` and then calling it in the CSS of the theme:

```
.regular,
.conversation,
.quote{
        background-color:{color:Regular Entry};
    }
```

I want to know if there is anyway to change this background color based on the **tag** of the post?

So, eg, say I only post regular entries but every one has a specific tag, out of a possible 6, which are all defined using `<meta name="color:tag1" content="#000000"/>`up to tag6. Is there a way to make the regular entry post change its bg color based on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your theme, add the [`{TagsAsClasses}` variable](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts) to the element containing a single post, for example, as value of the `class` attribute:

```html
<article class="post {TagsAsClasses}">
```

If you have tagged a post with "Foobar", you’ll find the `class` value `foobar` in the markup, e.g.:

```html
<article class="post foobar">
  <!-- … -->
</article>
```

You can use this as a hook in your CSS:

```css
.foobar {background-color:red;}
```

---

Side note: If you don’t want your users to use/see these tags, you can use a `_` prefix, as [explained in Tumblr’s staff blog](http://staff.tumblr.com/post/166789387/tag-tip-for-theme-designers).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the side note, that's pretty awesome!

Comment: That was brilliant, thanks - worked well. I used div instead of article so that I could just edit the theme's existing code but it works great, thanks :)